# How to retrieve the newest tag for an image?

Tags: docker

Given the following list of images, how would I retrieve the newest of the tags? (0.0.268) I guess it's possible with a combination of bash and Go template, but I can't figure it out...

> my-image 0.0.1    fd704b8d675e
>   my-image 0.0.2    9294a62d2c38
>   my-image 0.0.9    325326e8f7a2
>   my-image 0.0.10    b97c64b198d9
>   my-image 0.0.268    8a89b5fac348

For example:
By running the following command (`bx cr` is an IBM Bluemix CLI):

```
tagsList=$(bx cr images --format "{{if (eq .Repository \"myregistry/mynamespace/myimage\")}} {{.Tag}}{{end}}")
```

The echo of `$tagsList` is:

```
0.0.10 0.0.12 0.0.13 0.0.14 0.0.15 0.0.3 0.0.4 0.0.5 0.0.7
```

Out of this list I need the newest tag, which is `0.0.15`.

Comment: You could use the before filter to fetch an image created before or after a certain time. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#filtering

Comment: It needs to be more dynamic... I can't specify a timeframe.

Comment: I think I have a solution. Will update my answer

Comment: Try using tagsList=$(bx cr images --format "{{if (eq .Repository \"myregistry/mynamespace/myimage\")}} {{.Tag}\n}{{end}}")

Comment: It added "\n" instead of a newline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the last tag `<major_version>.<medium_version>.<minor_version>` :

**file.txt**:

```
my-image 0.10.1 fd704b8d675e
my-image 2.0.2 9294a62d2c38
my-image 0.0.9 325326e8f7a2
my-image 10.0.3 b97c64b198d9
my-image 10.0.10 b97c64b198d9
my-image 0.0.268 8a89b5fac348
my-image 10.0.6 b97c64b198d9
```

**last_tag.sh:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cut -d' ' -f2 file.txt \
    | sort -t . -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -nr \
    | head -1
```

`-t .` : precise the delimiter `.`
`-k n,n` : sort for the column n th (1-based)
`-nr` : sort number (no string) in decreasing order
`-k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3` : sort in order column 1, column 2, column 3,
that is to say major version, medium version then minor version.

Output:

```
10.0.10
```